# is it possible to use flask_socketio with connexion?

Tags: python, django, flask-socketio, connexion

I have a django app (frontend) which sends requests to a [connexion api](https://github.com/zalando/connexion) (backend). Now I want to add info to the user to know the progression of the request in real-time upon making a request to my api.

Example: from my django app, if I submit a form it will launch a request via `requests.post` and will show me some text ( ie: creating, deleting, updating ...)

I tried using flask-socketio but I found no example of how it could be done. (connexion with socketio)

PS: I want to use connexion for my api but it there is something else to use instead of socketio I don't mind

Comment: I honestly have never seen connexion mixed with Socket.IO, but I suppose you can get the Flask instance and attach any extension that you want. The other option would be to run a Socket.IO server separate from your connexion server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can. There is an open question in the connection repository https://github.com/zalando/connexion/issues/832 since 2018 unsolved.